# Spark Scala Testing - Reading from text file, generating additional output and writing to another text file

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to convert a Spark Python program to Scala. The goal of the program is to use an input data source, generate values based on the input source and then to write output.

The input is 1000,000 rows of notional property data with columns Property ID,  Property Name, Value of Property, Date of Valuation, Rental Income Per Year, Management Costs Per Year, Levy, Water and Net Rental Income. The output needs to be the property values projected for the next 100 years, i.e. 100 years in addition to the data for the first year (time 0).

This is my code so far:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.math.random

object PropertyInvestmentCalcs {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Users\\tjoha\\Documents\\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\hadoop-2.6.4\\bin\\")

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[6]").setAppName("Spark Pi")
    //.setJars(List("\\\\TJVRLAPTOP\\IntelliJ\\SBTScalaSparkPi\\target\\scala-2.10\\SBTScalaSparkPi-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"))
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)

    val rdd = spark.textFile("C:\\Users\\tjoha\\Google Drive\\Besigheid\\Spark Project\\Spark Project - Project Property Value and Costs.csv")

    def calculations(row:String)
    {
      val data = row.split(",").map(_.trim)
      val number_of_years = 100
      val rate = 0.06
      data :+ "0"
      for (i <- 1 to number_of_years) {
        data(2) = (data(2).toFloat * (1 + rate)).toString
        data(9) = i.toString
        yield (','.join(data))
      }
    }
    rdd.flatMap(calculations: String).saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\tjoha\\Google Drive\\Besigheid\\Spark Project\\output")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

I converted most of it from a Python program but am not sure whether my yield, join and rdd.FlatMap functions will work?

Since posting the function above I have made a couple of changes which was proposed. It seems that I am now stuck at the flatMap function which uses the calculations function. Any ideas?

```
object PropertyInvestmentCalcs {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Users\\tjoha\\Documents\\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\hadoop-2.6.4\\bin\\")

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[6]").setAppName("Spark Pi")
    //.setJars(List("\\\\TJVRLAPTOP\\IntelliJ\\SBTScalaSparkPi\\target\\scala-2.10\\SBTScalaSparkPi-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"))
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)

    val rdd = spark.textFile("C:\\Users\\tjoha\\Google Drive\\Besigheid\\Spark Project\\Spark Project - Project Property Value and Costs.csv")

    def calculations(row:String){
      val data = row.split(",").map(_.trim)
      val number_of_years = 100
      val rate = 0.06
      data :+ "0"
      for (i <- 1 to number_of_years) {
        data(2) = (data(2).toFloat * (1 + rate)).toString
        data(9) = i.toString
      }
      data.mkString(",")
    }
    rdd.flatMap(calculations).saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\tjoha\\Google Drive\\Besigheid\\Spark Project\\output")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Here is the compile error(s):

> Error:(30, 17) type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required:
>   TraversableOnce[?]
>       rdd.flatMap(calculations).saveAsTextFile("C:\Users\tjoha\Google Drive\Besigheid\Spark Project\output")

Thanks

Comment: Can u plz add more information about your input data and output data

Comment: some issues in your code: 
1) `data :+ "0"` - this doesn't change data, you should use `val data1 = data :+ "0"`
2) `yield (','.join(data))` - compiler error - yield not in place, use `for {...} yield ...`
3) `','.join(data)` is not as usual as `data.mkString(",")`

Comment: @Gabber Here is the data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By6QOZSxbb0bVWJtWHlaV0J0WTQ

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko thanks for the inputs. My program don't run yet. I'll keep spending some time on it. I'm still getting used programming in Spark and Scala - both technologies are new for me. I appreciate any inputs!

Comment: @Gabber for each input data record (row) there should be 100 output records produced. The output records are the projected future property values for the next 100 years. I'll quickly set up a workbook that contains more background about the input data, what needs to be done and the required output.

Comment: @Gabber Here is a workbook with much more detail on the inputs and outputs. The output sheet contains calculations for projections to be done. I only need the program above to be able to project one value, e.g. property value. I will be able to do the others myself. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By6QOZSxbb0bWjJqU3BuVVB1TkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you explain what are you actually doing ? your code calculations methods is weird. And also what is the desired output considering a sample of your data ?

Comment: Hi @eliasah, thanks for your interest. I want to build a small program to test the functionality of Spark. My end goal will be to start using Spark more often for financial projections. For the example I want to project property prices and rentals for the next 100 years. The input data is notional properties with values, rental income and expenses. The output should be each of these projected for 100 years. As there is 1000,000 input records, each of which needs to be projected for 100 years, there will be 100,000,000 output records. See the output sheet in my xlsx workbook for examples.

Comment: oh man that xlsx file is heavy to open ! you need to give me a sample. I can't open that file

Comment: Here is a smaller sample. Please confirm whether you can open it and understand it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By6QOZSxbb0bU1Q1dENiY3c1SVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @TJVR file size is too large,i'm not able to open it,can u plz add top 20 records

Comment: @Gabber this file includes a much smaller data set: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By6QOZSxbb0bU1Q1dENiY3c1SVE/view